# J2ME Exception types

Tags: java-me

I have read about `MIDletStateChangeException`. I wanna know other J2ME specific exceptions. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/. From there, I see:

- CertificateException
- ConnectionNotFoundException
- InvalidRecordIDException
- MIDletStateChangeException
- RecordStoreException
- RecordStoreFullException
- RecordStoreNotFoundException
- RecordStoreNotOpenException

Comment: and many more in other J2ME JSRs : 82, 75, 135, 256, 172, 234, 239, 184, 120, 211, 177, 179, 180, 205, 226, 229, 238 at www.jcp.org.